# Regex retorna False ao validar placa

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando validar uma placa de carros no formato : ABC1234
3 Letras e 4 números.

```
let regex = new RegExp("/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/");
let isvalid = regex.test('abc1234');
```

Quando coloco em outros sites,eles reconhecem a palavra,mas o código acima não reconhece.

Alguma idéia do que possa ser ?Obrigado.

Comment: Para criar a regex com a classe RegExp você não precisa das barras.

Comment: Olá,obrigado pela ajuda .Ao tirar as barras,ele retorna  true para qualquer string

Comment: Adicionando \b,retorna false para qualquer entrada,estou testando o código em : http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html

Comment: Usei esse seu Site ,tanto que foi lá que montei a expressão regular.Mas ao aplicar no javascript,ele não reconhece.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se for utilizar a classe `RegExp` você não precisará utilizar as barras; estas servem apenas para definir uma expressão regular direto, sem o uso da classe. Se ao retirar as barras sua expressão casa com outros valores que não deveriam casar, sua expressão está errada. Como você não informou detalhes sobre quais eram as outras *strings* que o resultado foi verdadeiro, mas deveria ser falso, supus que seriam para valores com mais que 3 letras seguidas por mais de 4 números ou variantes disso.

```js
let regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}");

const tests = [
    'abc1234',
    'ab1234', // falta uma letra
    'abc123', // falta um número
    '1234abc', // começa com número
    'abc12345', // tem um número a mais
    'abcd1234', // tem uma letra a mais
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(test, regex.test(test));
}
```

Se este for, de fato o problema, basta corrigir a expressão adicionando os caracteres `^` e `$` para definir o início e o fim de cada valor, para, assim, casar apenas com valores que começarem com 3 letras seguidas de 4 números e nada mais.

```js
let regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$");

const tests = [
    'abc1234',
    'ab1234', // falta uma letra
    'abc123', // falta um número
    '1234abc', // começa com número
    'abc12345', // tem um número a mais
    'abcd1234', // tem uma letra a mais
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(test, regex.test(test));
}
```

Utilizando as barras ao invés da classe ficaria:

```js
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/;

const tests = [
    'abc1234',
    'ab1234', // falta uma letra
    'abc123', // falta um número
    '1234abc', // começa com número
    'abc12345', // tem um número a mais
    'abcd1234', // tem uma letra a mais
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(test, regex.test(test));
}
```

Vale comentar que neste caso é preferível o uso da notação com barras pois a expressão é constante. Isso deixa o código mais performático e mais semântico. Prefira utilizar a classe `RexExp` apenas quando a expressão puder variar.

Comment: Obrigado,Resolveu meu problema ,não sabia sobre ^ e $

Answer (score 5):

Complementando, você pode também delimitar usando o meta-caractere `\b` usando expressão literal, adicionando também o `^` que define o início da string:

```js
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}\b/;
console.log(regex.test('abc1234')); // correto
console.log(regex.test('abc12345')); // 5 números
console.log(regex.test('abcd2345')); // 4 letras
console.log(regex.test('abc145')); // 3 números
console.log(regex.test('ab2145')); // 2 letras
```

Comment: Acho que o motivo de não ter funcionado quando você pediu para adicionar o \b,foi que a expressão regular   /[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}\b/ estava entre aspas.

Comment: Se for para usar delimitador, eu poria antes e depois. Identificar uma placa no meio de uma string, no lugar de ser apenas no começo da string

Answer (score 2):

Para validar o padrão mercosul e padrão atual (Br) de placas, utilize este script simples para validação de placas padrão mercosul e placas atuais utilizando Javascript (vanilla) RegEx:

```
let plate = "ABC1234";
let plateMerc = "ABC1D23"

const regexPlate = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/;
const regexPlateMerc = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}$/;

function validatePlate(plate) {
  if(regexPlate.test(plate)){
    console.warn('Placa válida (padrão atual)');
    return true
  }
  else if(regexPlateMerc.test(plate)){
    console.warn('Placa válida (padrão mercosul)');
    return true
  }
  else {
    console.error('Placa inválida no padrão atual e mercosul');
    return false
  }
```

Comment: Sua resposta não contempla as motocicletas que possuem padrão LLL NN LN (em que L é letra e N, número).

Comment: o ```{1}``` é desnecessário.